# iPhone website and position fixed delay on the first scroll

Tags: iphone, css, web

I'm using css fixed position on my mobile website for a top and bottom navigation bar and I noticed a bug on my iPhone browsers (Safari and Chrome) : the position fixed is not working until the end of the first scroll... then it's working fine for all the next scrolls.

**Example :**

http://jsbin.com/ugaraf/1

**Screenshots :**

Bug during the first scroll down after refresh : http://goo.gl/yD5iz

Then working fine : http://goo.gl/mUKSn

Do you experience the same thing ? Is there any way to fix that ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a website that has the fixed top and is working fine with safari mobile and chrome.

The css of this specific DIV is

```
#navbar{

 width:100%;
 height:80px;
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
 border-bottom:4px solid #007f3f;
 position:fixed;
 z-index:10;

}
```

In my case, the z-index is set due to other divs being in a `position:relative`.

At least for the top one, you don't really need the `top:0`
Try without it and post some feedback.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This enables hardware acceleration on iOS devices:

```
.youraffixelement {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```